# how to open youtube on big screen when clicked played button in react js

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I just started learning to react and now I'm in the problem I just want to open a youtube player in big screen when I click the play button and I don't know how to do it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { GetVideo } from "../../api";
import Youtube from "react-youtube";

const Media = ({ id, isMovie }) => {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getVideoData = async () => {
      await GetVideo(isMovie, id).then((response) => {
        const trailer = response.data.results.find(
          (video) => video.name === "Official Trailer"
        );
        setVideo(trailer);

      });
    };
    getVideoData();
  }, [isMovie, id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Youtube videoId={video.key} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Media;
```

Comment: What do you mean by big screen ?

Comment: Big screen means just open in custom width and height like 1000px !

Comment: @shubhamtarpara have you tried my solution? Did it work?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea yes i tried that but didnt worked! we just have to to set playinline to 0 only ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an `opts` object, which accepts `height` and `width` as properties. I'd also look for a `fullscreen` flag (or send a pull request)

Edit: for full screen, I think it's `opts.playerVars.playsinline` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playsinline))

Comment: <Youtube
        videoId={video.key}
        opts={{
          width: '600px',
          height: '600px',
          playerVars: {
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            rel: 0,
            playsinline: 1,
            fs: 1,
            controls: 0,
            enablejsapi: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            disablekb: 1,
            autohide: 1,
            autoplay: 0,
            loop: 0,
            volume: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3
          },
        }}

not working bro

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `playsinline` property inside the `opts` object.

The playsinline parameter controls whether videos play inline or fullscreen in an HTML5 player on iOS. Setting the value to 1 causes inline playback.

Also, you can set custom width and height by passing these properties inside the `opts`.

Comment: Means i need to have playsinline to 1 and give width and height too ?